# Intermittent slowness with apache web application interesting log findings (169.254.230.252)

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

IP Config OF SERVER

C:\PHPPOS\php>ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : POS-4
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 52-10-B3-FD-6A-9B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-10-B3-FD-8F-CB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-10-B3-FD-6A-9B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Netwo
rk Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-10-B3-FD-6A-9B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c05f:d8d9:b99e:31c1%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.114(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 70258867
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-99-7E-D7-D8-CB-8A-52-E8-E6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D8-CB-8A-52-E8-E6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::560:eab9:48ab:e6fc%3(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.230.252(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 64539530
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-99-7E-D7-D8-CB-8A-52-E8-E6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.15.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{7E7090E8-A9A6-4625-85DA-930CC2B1A44D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{274F261F-698B-4FFD-9C1A-35ED730F0A8C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\PHPPOS\php>
```

We are having an odd problem with a web application where a user cannot connect sometimes and it just hangs. We load tested the server with a ton of requests and it only went to 10% CPU at the max.

This is all in a local network.

The issue does NOT happen from the server computer; only from the clients.

I noticed in the access log there is an IP address of 169.254.230.252 (THIS IS THE SERVER) in the log. Why wouldn't it report the 192.x address that has a connection. Could this be related to why the client has dropped connections/timeouts?

```
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:31 +1000] "POST /index.php/customers/save HTTP/1.1" 200 118
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:32 +1000] "POST /index.php/sales/select_customer HTTP/1.1" 200 17247
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:32 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales HTTP/1.1" 200 32065
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:32 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/categories?_=1436500475731 HTTP/1.1" 200 712
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:40 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/item_search?term=pp&_=1436500475732 HTTP/1.1" 200 7162
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:41 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/item_search?term=pp..&_=1436500475733 HTTP/1.1" 200 2
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:43 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/item_search?term=pp&_=1436500475734 HTTP/1.1" 200 7162
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:44 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/item_search?term=pp000&_=1436500475735 HTTP/1.1" 200 4062
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:45 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/item_search?term=pp0003&_=1436500475736 HTTP/1.1" 200 907
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:47 +1000] "GET /index.php/sales/item_search?term=pp00003&_=1436500475737 HTTP/1.1" 200 112
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:48 +1000] "POST /index.php/sales/add HTTP/1.1" 200 22642
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:56 +1000] "POST /index.php/sales/edit_item/1?payment_type=PayPal HTTP/1.1" 200 22642
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:54:57 +1000] "POST /index.php/sales/add_payment HTTP/1.1" 200 23288
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:55:00 +1000] "POST /index.php/sales/complete HTTP/1.1" 200 17144
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:55:00 +1000] "GET /index.php/app_files/view/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1911
192.168.15.111 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:55:00 +1000] "GET /index.php/barcode?barcode=POS%2031269&text=POS%2031269 HTTP/1.1" 200 1435
192.168.15.112 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:56:25 +1000] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1436496687913 HTTP/1.1" 200 10
169.254.230.252 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:57:42 +1000] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1436488662694 HTTP/1.1" 200 10
192.168.15.113 - - [10/Jul/2015:13:58:11 +1000] "GET /index.php/home/keep_alive?_=1436497998120 HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

Comment: Check your DHCP is configured correctly. A 169 address is when the device cannot communicate or cannot get an IP Address from the DHCP server. "Does this mean the user that was connected is changing ip addresses to a default value for some reason?" > No, a 169 IP address is assigned automatically (APIPA) by the computer not the user.

Comment: We have determined that the 169 address is the ethernet interface on the server. It also has a wireless interface turned on. Could having both on cause issues?

Comment: Nope, that won't have anything do to with it. A 169 address is when a computer cannot receive an IP Address from the DHCP server. "The issue does NOT happen from the server computer; only from the clients." > The reason your server doesn't have a 169 address is because it is most likely using a static IP. It would be useful to do an ipconfig /all from the server and the client machine and post results here.

Comment: I posted ip config

Comment: This is the server. I thought before the 169 was a client but I examined more and it was the server. I don't have access to the client right now; but I will tonight.

Comment: Last comment before I have to leave the office, do you have a default gateway set up? Make sure your default gateway and subnet mask are configured correctly + try to assign a static IP.

Comment: I will give it a shot in about 7 hours. I think the static IP might be the way to go. Should I disable wireless too?